# Creating different html file for each blog posts

Tags: html

I have wonder there are any way to split single html file into several one. I have single index file which contains many blog posts. I want to create a different html file for each blog posts and import them or link them to main html file.

Example;

```
   <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
           <header>
           </header>
           <article>
                <div id="blog-post-1">
                      <!-- Content of blog post -->
                </div>
                <div id="blog-post-2">
                      <!-- Content of blog post -->
                </div>
                <div id="blog-post-3">
                      <!-- Content of blog post -->
                </div>
                <div id="blog-post-4">
                      <!-- Content of blog post -->
                </div>
                <div id="blog-post-5">
                      <!-- Content of blog post -->
                </div>
           </article>
```

I just want to create a different file for each blog posts; for above case 5 different html files. Then, link or import them in main html body. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show an external web page you can use Iframe's
You use it like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.website.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Good luck!

Comment: In main html, I want show blog post 1. I donot want give link to text.